# JSP - Verifying Checkbox button causing long loading time?

Tags: java, jsp, checkbox

I have the following:

`song.jsp`

```
<form action='cart' method='POST'>
            <table style="width:1000px" style="text-align:center">                  
                <c:set var="count" value="0" scope="page" />
                <c:forEach var="item" items="${song.songInfo}">                         
                    <c:set var="split" value="${fn:split(item,';')}" />                         
                    <tr>
                      <td>${split[0]}</td>
                      <td>${split[1]}</td>
                      <td>${split[2]}</td>
                      <td>${split[3]}</td>
                      <td>${split[4]}</td>
                      <td>${split[5]}</td>
                      <td>${split[6]}</td>                                    
                      <td><input type="checkbox" name="checked"></td> 
                      <td><input type="hidden" name="id${count}" value="${split[7]}}"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <c:set var="count" value="${count + 1}" scope="page"/>  
                </c:forEach>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart"/>
        </form>
```

`cartServlet.java`

```
while (request.getParameterMap().containsKey("id" + counter)){
            String check = request.getParameter("checked" + counter);   
            if (check != null){ // ******    THIS ****************
                String songID = request.getParameter("id" + counter);
                System.out.println(songID);
                cartBean.setCartInfo(songID);               
                ++counter;
            }

    }
```

I am finding that when I add the line `if (check != null){...}`, my program takes an incredibly long time to load. I have never actually waited for it to finish... so I'm not even sure whether the program has frozen. If I remove this line however, everything works normally?

Would anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `++counter;` outside of `if` statement. Otherwise you can have infinite loop.